# @Embedded java persistence annotation and DAO

Tags: java, jpa

Does anyone know if Embedded classes(jpa @embedded annotation) can be used with data access objects in JAVA? I am trying to figure out a way to link multiple classes together using a single primary key. I am trying not to use the one-to-one relationship multiple times in my project in order to link them together in the database. I prefer to have them in the same table. If it is possible to use the @Embedded how do I access the fields of the embedded classes?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable`? What have you tried? Please provide more info about your issue, currently looks more like a use case/requirement to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they can be used. All you need to do is specify its access properly. The class which you want to embed you will use `@Embeddable @Access(AccessType.FIELD)` on top of it. And in main class you will use `@Embedded` over the field.

You will find complete example over [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JPA/0600__JPA_Embeddable.htm)

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks so much!!